# How to Validate build number using regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have a build number in the format of DGTS_2.11.2311231231 , I would like to validate the input and exit if the format is not matching , I have tried to create something like this, but it is not working , please help me

```
version=$1
version_checked=$(echo $version | sed -e 'DGTS_\/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]{1,2}\+\.[0-9]{1,10}/d')
version_checked=DGTS_*
if [[ -z $version_checked ]]; then
echo "$version is the right format"
else
 echo "$version_checked is not  in the right format, please use XX.XX.XX format (ie: DGTS_2.10.3)"
exit
```

This snippet is not validating if the input is incorrect format

Comment: What the rules for the build number?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the first two numerical areas can be one or two digits, while the last is in the range 1-10. There are a couple issues with your program logic and syntax that aren't applicable to the regex itself which I removed:

```
#!/bin/bash

version=$1

if [[ $version =~ ^DGTS_([0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,10}$ ]]; then
  echo "$version is the right format"
else
  echo "$version is not in the right format, please use XX.XX.XX format (ie: DGTS_2.10.3)"
  exit
fi
```

Per your request, here's a regex that works with an optional fourth quadrant and allows `DGTS_2.11.0.4661505` to pass:

```
^DGTS_([0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,10}(\.[0-9]{1,10})?$
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , Unfortunately its not working for the valid input

Comment: What input is failing? The only example you provided, `DGTS_2.11.2311231231`, passes: `$ ./a.sh DGTS_2.11.2311231231`
`DGTS_2.11.2311231231 is the right format`

Comment: The exact input is DGTS_2.11.0.4661505 , I updated the regex line $version =~ ^DGTS_([0-9]{1,2}\.){3}[0-9]{1,10}$ and   I think this should  pass if the above input is passing, As you pointed out DGTS_2.11.2311231231 input is working , but DGTS_2.11.0.4661505 is not working

Comment: OK, you didn't specify that 4 quadrants were possible in the question. I'll add that now.